# How to call Javascript method in webservice using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services

In Webservice is it possible to call javascript function. [Or] In Webservice is it possible to redirect page. I have used this(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");), But, i didn't find any sol for it. Please, reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you mistaken **WebApplication** for **WebService**?

Comment: In Web service only. Rohit

Comment: How to create a global exception handler for a Web Service

Comment: In your global.asax, return the corresponding HTTP error code with message.

Comment: When we get any error in web service Catch it is not navigating to global.ascx.cs page

Comment: http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2005/09/05/HowToCreateAGlobalExceptionHandlerForAWebService.aspx

Comment: It is not working. When we get any exception error is not firing in Global.ascx.cs page. Please, Find correct for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: From somewhere in your comments I read you are using WebAPI, and if so there are so many good tutorials. Try something and comeback if you have a problem. [Simple Google Search Result](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=web%20api%20global%20exception%20handler)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call JS function from WebMethod.

But there is a trick you can set your Webmethod response in such way that on the success it returns some parameter or your URL which you want to redirect.

Something like

```
success: function(response){
  var r=response.d;
  window.location.href = r;
}
```

---

Or

You need to build a SOAP extension.

**Application_Error** never fires for WebService

The reason for this is that the HTTP handler for XML Web services consumes any exception that occurs while an XML Web service is executing and turns it into a SOAP fault prior to the `Application_Error` event is called. To achieve exception handling you need to write a custom SOAP extension or HTTPModule.

Check this links:

1. [Throwing Better .NET Exceptions with SOAP and HTTP](http://blog.codinghorror.com/throwing-better-net-exceptions-with-soap-and-http/)
2. [User-Friendly ASP.NET Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8049/User-Friendly-ASP-NET-Exception-Handling)

Comment: SOrry, In datatable we cannot handle any return. that's y i need to handle in webservice only.

Comment: How to create a global exception handler for a Web Service

Comment: I need to handle error in catch & then i need to navigate it to other page using webservice.Where I have this( //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
                //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");), But, it did not worked me

Comment: You need to build  SOAP extension to catch Exception, which occurs in your Webservice

Comment: Ya, I used it. But, it is unable to catch the exception in Global.ascx.cs page. I have used like this( void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Error.aspx");). Error in Web service it is not going to Global.ascx page.. Thank You for ur quick reply(Satinder).

Comment: catch all unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET Web Api catch in global.ascx.cs. Is it possible

Comment: i think @tarunsatepuri you need to be clear with the question you want to be answered and only one question to be asked at one time ..